# How to use data from every row to create a matrix by loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a data frame like

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),c=c(7,8,9),d=c(10,11,12))
  a b c  d
1 1 4 7 10
2 2 5 8 11
3 3 6 9 12
```

I want to use every row to create 3 (nrow(df)) 2*2 matrixes. 1st use 1,4,7,10, 2nd use 2,5,8,11, 3rd use 3,6,9,12. So that I can get 3 matrixes. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `split` to split up the dataset into `list` and use `matrix`

```
lapply(split.default(as.matrix(df), row(df)), matrix, 2)
```

If we need the matrix columns to be 1, 7 followed by 4, 10, use the `byrow=TRUE`

```
lapply(split.default(as.matrix(df), row(df)), matrix, 2, byrow=TRUE)
```

---

Or use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` and wrap it with `list` to get a `list` output

```
do.call("c", apply(df, 1, function(x) list(matrix(x, ncol=2))))
```

---

If we need a `for` loop, preassign `a` as a `list` with `length` equal to the number of rows of 'df'

```
a <- vector("list", nrow(df))
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){ a[[i]] <- matrix(unlist(df[i,]), ncol=2)}
a
```

Or if it can be stored as `array`

```
array(t(df), c(2, 2, 3))
```

Comment: I tried array for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  a<-array(c(df$a[i],df$b[i],df$c[i],df$d[i]),dim = c(2,2,3))
}

Comment: @AllenYu Your method will replace `a` in each loop.  You may have to preassign `a` as a `list` of length 3 and use `a[[i]] <- `

Answer (score 4):

Or using `map`:

```
m <- matrix(c(t(df)), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
p <- 2 # number of rows
Map(function(i,j) m[i:j,], seq(1,nrow(m),p), seq(p,nrow(m),p))

# [[1]]
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    7   10

# [[2]]
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    5
# [2,]    8   11

# [[3]]
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    6
# [2,]    9   12
```

Comment: With `mapply`, an alternative is `do.call(Map, c(function(...) matrix(c(...), 2, 2), df))` too. (or its equivalent `.mapply(function(...) matrix(c(...), 2, 2), df, NULL)`)